# Delete worksheet and close excel file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm creating program that will collect worksheet names from a text file and use these to delete the worksheets in the user selected workbook.

I'm able to collect the name and the following delete routine displays no error as well.

```
Try
Dim sheetname As String = ""
Dim indexcounter As Integer = 0

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For index As Integer = 0 To worksheet_remove.Length - 1 Step 1
    sheetname = CStr(worksheet_remove(Index))    'worksheet_remove is an array that has the stored excel sheets names.

    For Each ws In objWorkBook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheetname Then ws.delete()
    Next
Next

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
MessageBox.Show ("complete")

Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show (ex.toString)
Finally
GC.Collect()
End Try
```

However, when the following routine is executed during form close event.

```
objWorkBook.Save()
objWorkBook.Close()
objWorkBook = Nothing
objWorkSheets = Nothing
objExcel.Quit()
```

This error appears

[image]

If I were to type the sheetname to delete directly and then run the program it works fine. But I cannot figure out why the program stops working when it has to use worksheet name from an array.

Thank You